# Can pandas.DataFrame have list type column?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to create pandas.DataFrame which includes list type field?

For example, I'd like to load the following csv to pandas.DataFrame:

```
id,scores
1,"[1,2,3,4]"
2,"[1,2]"
3,"[0,2,4]"
```

Comment: Yes but I'd advise against storing non-scalar values as elements as it makes filtering and lookup a pain to the point that it makes it not worthwile

Comment: @EdChum Good point. I'll hesitate filtering or lookup by a key which stores a non-scalar values. However, how about using non-scalar fields as data which are not used for a key? It still occurs slower lookup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strip the double quotes:

```
id,scores
1, [1,2,3,4]
2, [1,2]
3, [0,2,4]
```

And you should be able to do this:

```
query = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [2, [1,2]], [3, [0,2,4]]]
df = pandas.DataFrame(query, columns=['id', 'scores'])
print df
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u'''id,scores  
1,"[1,2,3,4]"
2,"[1,2]"
3,"[0,2,4]"'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=',', index_col=[0] )
print df
     scores  
id           
1   [1,2,3,4]
2       [1,2]
3     [0,2,4]
```

But dtype of column scores is `object`, not list.

One approach use [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) and `converters`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from ast import literal_eval

temp=u'''id,scores
1,"[1,2,3,4]"
2,"[1,2]"
3,"[0,2,4]"'''

def converter(x):
    #define format of datetime
    return literal_eval(x)

#define each column
converters={'scores': converter}

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=',', converters=converters)
print df
   id        scores
0   1  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1   2        [1, 2]
2   3     [0, 2, 4]

#check lists:
print 2 in df.scores[2]
#True

print 1 in df.scores[2]
#False
```