# Alternative To Storing List in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, data-science

I have a dataframe storing time series data of users in a system, such as:

```
time      action    playerID  amount    outcome
------------------------------------------------
10:00:00  sell      1         10        win
09:58:10  buy       2         15        lose
09:55:00  leave     2         NaN       NaN
09:55:00  enter     6         NaN       NaN
```

I know what users are in the system at start, and I am trying to figure out the best way to store the "system state" at each line. For example, at the start, there are 5 players in the system, the system state is `(1,2,3,4,5)`. At 09:55:00, the system state changes to `(1,3,4,5,6)`.

Referencing this post, [Can pandas.DataFrame have list type column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197519/can-pandas-dataframe-have-list-type-column/34197801), one way to do it would be to declare a new field with an empty list, and then at every `leave` and `enter` record, do a replace on the list.

```
time      action    playerID  amount    outcome    state
--------------------------------------------------------------
10:00:00  sell      1         10        win        [1,2,3,4,5]
09:58:10  buy       2         15        lose       [1,2,3,4,5]
09:55:00  leave     2         NaN       NaN        [1,3,4,5]
09:55:00  enter     6         NaN       NaN        [1,3,4,5,6]
```

My issue with this is that I will then do analytics on the different states (there are many more data points in the table), and doing lookups and filters on the field based on a list seems like it would be unreliable and/or computationally expensive.

One alternative I thought of would be to store the different states in a dictionary, each time I come across a new combination in the data, add it as a **value** to the dictionary and autoincrement the **key** and give each state an ID which can be stored in the dataframe (code below is not tested, just for example purposes):

```
states = {1:[1,2,3,4,5]}
statesID = 1
state = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in df:
    if i['action'] == 'leave':
        state.remove(i['playerID'])
    if i['action'] == 'enter':
        state.append(i['playerID'])
    state = state.sort()
    if len(state) == 5 & state not in states.values():
        statesID += 1
        states[statesID] = statesID
    i['state'] = statesID
```

The downside to this approach is that I am to understand that iterating through a data frame is inefficient and should be avoided

I am coming from more of a SQL background, which is why my instinct is to store the state "ID" in the data frame. Is there a more efficient or more "pythonic" way?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think storing it as list would be `unreliable`. I get your concerns regarding efficiency. depending on what is needed in downstream analytics, perhaps storing the state as `set` would be more efficient than `list`, or numpy arrays might turn out to be the right container. Could you update the question with more details of the specific downstream analysis steps you're trying to optimize, and since this is a performance-related question, perhaps a slightly bigger dataset (in a pastebin) that solvers can refer to when presenting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the list as a string `S`

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5] 
S=str(L)
```

Depending on your workflow for the analysis that follows, you can then turn the string back to an array (or a list) of integers

```
np.array(S.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(', '), dtype=int)
```

Here a snippet on the ipython shell

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [2]: L=[1,2,3,4,5]                                                                                                  

In [3]: S=str(L)                                                                                                       

In [4]: S                                                                                                              
Out[4]: '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'

In [5]: np.array(S.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(', '), dtype=int)                                                 
Out[5]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [6]: list(np.array(S.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(', '), dtype=int) )                                          
Out[6]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```