# How to insert dictionary values into a dataframe if the string in the dataframe is equal to the key of the dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python so any help would be appreciated. I am creating a script to produce load case combinations for an engineering problem. Is there a concise way replacing the values of a pandas dataframe like input_eq below with a list dictionary values when the key of the dictionary is == to the string in the dataframe?

```
input_eq=         
          1st_coeff 1st_load  2nd_coeff 2nd_load  3rd_coeff 3rd_load  4th_coeff 4th_load  5th_coeff  ... 6th_load  7th_coeff  7th_load  8th_coeff 8th_load  9th_coeff  9th_load  10th_coeff 10th_load
Load case                                                                                             ...
SLSc4-1         1.00        G       1.00       GH      1.000      G0I        0.5       GT       0.50  ...    QLbis        0.3     QTbis        0.6    Qwbis        1.0  QWLEFbis         0.2    Dyna_m
ULSf1b-1        1.35        G       1.35   G0Ibis      0.675       GT        1.5       QC       0.45  ...    Qwbis        1.2  QWLEFbis        NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN


load_variant_dict={'G': ['G'], 'G0I': ['G0I'], 'G0Ibis': ['G0Ibis', '0'], 'GH': ['GH'], 'GT': ['GT'], 'QC': ['QC'], 'QLbis': ['LC0', 'QL'], 'QTbis': ['LC0', 'Qtsummer', 'Qtwinter'], 'Qwbis': ['LC0', 'QwN', 'QwW', 'QwE', 'QwS'], 'QWLEFbis': ['LC0', 'QWLEF'], 'Dyna_m': ['Dyna_m_1', 'Dyna_m_2', 'Dyna_m_3', 'Dyna_m_4', 'Dyna_m_5', 'Dyna_m_6', 'Dyna_m_7', 'Dyna_m_8', 'Dyna_m_9', 'Dyna_m_10', 'Dyna_m_11', 'Dyna_m_12', 'Dyna_m_13', 'Dyna_m_14', 'Dyna_m_15', 'Dyna_m_16', 'Dyna_m_17', 'Dyna_m_18', 'Dyna_m_19', 'Dyna_m_20', 'Dyna_m_21', 'Dyna_m_22', 'Dyna_m_23', 'Dyna_m_24'], 'Aexpbis': ['AexpN', 'AexpW', 'AexpE', 'AexpS'], 'AWL': ['AWL'], 'AT': ['AT'], 'ATp': ['ATdp', 'Atsp'], 'ATw': ['ATwN', 'ATwW', 'ATwE', 'ATwS']}
```

Ideally for an output I want a list within the cells where there is more than one variant. This is so I can use cartesian product on the dataframe to produce all the possible load combinations.
I have tried using a .replace() method but once there is more than 1 variant such as in the 2nd_load column, the script returns the following error.

```
>>> input_eq_b= input_eq_a.replace({'2nd_load':input_var_dict})

ValueError: cannot assign mismatch length to masked array
>>> print(input_eq_b)
```

I assume this is because the function cannot replace a string with a list of strings so any help on alternatives would be great!

```
Desired output example:

Load case  1st_coeff 1st_load  2nd_coeff    2nd_load  3rd_coeff 3rd_load  4th_coeff 4th_load  5th_coeff                 5th_load  6th_coeff                   6th_load  7th_coeff     7th_load  8th_coeff  8th_load  \
  ULSf1b-1       1.35        G       1.35  [G0Ibis,0]      0.675       GT        1.5       QC       0.45  [LCO,Qtsummer,Qtwinter]        0.9  [LC0, QwN, QwW, QwE, QwS]        1.2  [LCO,QWLEF]        NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['a','b','c']})
print('before:\n', df)
md = {'a' : ['a1','a2','a3'], 'b' : ['b1','b2']}
df['col1'] = [md.get(key,key) for key in df['col1']]
print('after:\n',df)
```

that produces what looks like the desired output for this toy example

```
before:
   col1
0    a
1    b
2    c
after:
            col1
0  [a1, a2, a3]
1      [b1, b2]
2             c
```

Note `dict.get(a,b)`method that returs dict[a] if a is an existing key and b if a is not in the keys

Having lists as cells in DataFrames is possible (as in the example above) but generally not considered a good idea, see some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197519/can-pandas-dataframe-have-list-type-column)